# Adding label in scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

My problem : I have a white window and I don't understand why.
I tried some solutions but nothing works.
Thx for your help.

```
CGFloat largeurDevice = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat longueurDevice = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGRect rectScrollView = CGRectMake(0,longueurDevice/2,largeurDevice,longueurDevice/2);
UIScrollView *monScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:rectScrollView];
[self.view addSubview: monScrollView];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    CGRect rectImage = CGRectMake(0,longueurDevice/2+i*30,320,30); // Définition d'un rectangle
    CGRect rectLabel = CGRectMake(10,longueurDevice/2+i*30,320,30);

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectImage];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barreTest.png"];
    [monScrollView addSubview: imageView];

    UILabel *monLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: rectLabel];
    monLabel.text = @"Ceci est un label";
    [monScrollView addSubview: monLabel];
}
```

Comment: You are adding the image views and labels below the visible height of the scroll view. This may or may not be what you want. If you do, you also need to set the scroll view's `contentSize` to be big enough for the added views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UIlabel and UIImageView frame are seated out of visible bounds.

as example if you set

```
CGRect rectImage = CGRectMake(0,i*30,320,30);
CGRect rectLabel = CGRectMake(10,(i*30)+40,320,30);
```

you will be able to see them on the scrollview. Please set frame properly to see your UI components and also set content size of scroll view to make it scrolling. If your content size is bigger the scrollview frame, scroll view will be able to scroll,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
Now it works. If you have any advice for me, it will be a pleasure to me.

```
int max = 10;
CGFloat largeurDevice = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat longueurDevice = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGRect rectScrollView = CGRectMake(0,longueurDevice/2,largeurDevice,longueurDevice/2);
UIScrollView *monScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:rectScrollView];
monScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(largeurDevice,30*max);
[self.view addSubview: monScrollView];

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    CGRect rectImage = CGRectMake(0,i*30,largeurDevice,30); // Définition d'un rectangle
    CGRect rectLabel = CGRectMake(10,i*30,largeurDevice,30);
    CGRect rectBututton = CGRectMake(largeurDevice-20,longueurDevice/2+i*30,10,10);

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectImage];
     imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barreTest.png"];
    [monScrollView addSubview: imageView];

    UILabel *monLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: rectLabel];
    monLabel.text = @"Ceci est un label";
    [monScrollView addSubview: monLabel];
}
```